# the meaning of I'd you to do something

Tags: meaning-in-context

ELIZABETH:

> First off, I just want to tell you that I think that people are the most important aspect of a company. That's why I'd you to head up our new intern program.

I wonder what is the meaning of "I'd you". Dictionaries and searching in the internet couldn't help me. I guess it is probably the short form of "I would like you". Am I right? If I **am** right, is that short form usage common in spoken English?

Comment: This is clearly a transcription error: the word 'like' has been dropped. That would not occur in either spoken or written English.

Comment: @Stoney - Another example of why it's so important to [tell us where you found your quote](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-that-confuses-you).

Comment: you can find that sentences in this address "http://www.englishtown.com/community/channels/lesson2.aspx?ptn=memb&hash=bGVzc29uX2lkPTYzMSZ0YWI9MSZwdG49bm9uZSZzaWQ9MTk4MDE1NTImbGlkPTYzMSZlZD0yMDE0LTEwLTA5VDE3JTNhMzAlM2EwMCZjdHI9dWsmbG5nPWVuJmNjPSZldGFnPUUxMTM4ODBfbWVtYiZlZXZlcj000&etag=E113880_memb&eever=4"

Answer (score 1):

The word **like** is missing between I'd and you in this sentence. Whoever wrote the original sentence made a mistake. This would never be written or spoken in English as StoneyB mentioned in their comment.

Comment: Another acceptable way the same sentence could be written would be: "That's why I want you to head up our new intern program."